# .Net Core 2.1 Cache Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can't seem to get it working. Really simple scenario...

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)">
    @DateTime.Now
</cache>
```

Running this in VS2017 in IISExpress (same behaviour in IIS 10 too btw) and hitting refresh in the browser (Chrome) just gives me the current time? I'm using .Net Core 2.1. I'm trying it in a partial and a view component and it just doesn't cache.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

For the record, I've added..

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

to the Startup ConfigureServices method (although according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1), I shouldn't even need to do this as it is added automatically - it says so right at the bottom).

This is also using Razor pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that you haven't added the tag helpers. As a troubleshooting step, add the tag helpers to the view that has the `<cache>` element.

**_SomePartial.cshtml**

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)">
    @DateTime.Now
</cache>
```

If that solves the problem, you will probably want to make [the tag helpers available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available) to an entire directory instead of just to one file. Do that by moving the `addTagHelper` directive to a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Comment: Spot on. This was the issue. Appreciate your answer. Shame the documentation didn't include this little detail (not even the helper section documentation from what I can see). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be another possibility that makes `cache` tag helper not working.

I also had the same problem even though I'd added Microsoft tag helpers properly, my mistake was that I used `DateTime.Now` for `expires-on` attribute. see below

`<cache expires-on="DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)">
    @DateTime.Now
</cache>`

now date time `DateTime.Now` should not be used for `cache`tag helper because every time that the page is refreshed the `expires-on` value will be changed and cause the framework re-add the entry to cache with the new `expires-on`.

I changed `expires-on="DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)"` to `expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200)"` and it worked.